# How to get Fireth of July achievement in Hoard?

Tags: achievements, hoard

In Hoard there is a new achievement:

> Fireth of July - Cause 20 groups of
>   fireworks to go off in a Hoard Mode
>   level

but I have no idea how to get it, it seems ridiculously hard. Do you have some suggestions to succeed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fireworks are triggered when a knight returns a princess to a castle. This means you kill a carriage and don't take the princess.

I used the first HOARD level, because it has the longest expected goal times (so they must expect you to survive longer). I started out each round by killing as many towns as possible, and keeping the archer count down afterwards. Towns give you a nice initial gold boost.

Whenever a magic tower springs up early on, killing it will give you lots of gold (and likely upgrade your dragon). They're also the most annoying thing on the map late-game (second being archers).

Make sure to use powerups - they're great for picking off groups of knights and individual magic towers. As for archers, you can run by them and not die as long as you don't stop.

Once you're good at simply surviving, you have two secondary goals:

1. Kill princess carriages, and let knights take the princesses. When a knight returns a princess to a castle, that triggers fireworks. You need to do this twenty times.
2. Don't get hurt. If you get hurt, you need to take a princess yourself, and that's one less firework :)

It took about a six minute round to get the achievement, after about 45 minutes of practice (and the game was fun enough I didn't mind the practice). When it gets that far into the game, you'll start seeing two or three carriages together you can kill for fireworks.

Comment: Very funny! I spent 1 hour and 15 minutes trying to get the achievement, but nothing, even if I resisted 8 minutes or more. I finally desisted, but when I checked my Steam camp page the achievement was there. I got it in the first 30 minutes but it didn't appear the notification in game :)

Comment: BSG has re-jiggered the requirements for this achievement, dropping the number of fireworks required down to 12. I suspect it was due in part to a large outcry from the user base on their forums. Quite honestly, pulling off 20 of them in a single play seemed darned near impossible. Exploiting loopholes in specific maps appears to be the only way to get the full 20.

Comment: oh cmon, I didn't exploit any map loopholes :) just took some practice

Answer (score 2):

For the achievement **Fireth of July** you need 20 princesses to be rescued and returned to a  castle by a knight. Each rescued princess sets off a firework at the castle.

You can get some tactics and tipps from this video:

There's also a bug(?)/trick you can try to use on the first Hoard map, as explained by YouTube user *Stormtempte*:

> "There is a 2 tile lake that knights cannot cross. There are no castle or towns near it. Only 1 farm, and 4 immediate threat mage tower spawns, with 2 further out. By staying in that corner, burning mage towers as they come, and knights as they come, you can 'idle' there for 10+ minutes. Giving giants plenty of time to spawn and destroy carts for you."

Answer (score 0):

There is now a fireworks cart that will travel the same way as a commodity (straw) cart.

When destroyed, the fireworks go off.

(If you are close to the cart when the fireworks go off, you will receive damage)